# Select columns of tibbles in a list based on the values from the other list

Tags: r, list, purrr, tibble

I have a list of tibbles:

```
dfs <- list()
dfs[["mtcars"]] <- mtcars
dfs[["iris"]] <- iris
dfs[["ToothGrowth"]] <- ToothGrowth
```

I want to apply a function to the list that selects the columns of tibbles based on this list:

```
select_columns <- list()
select_columns[["mtcars"]] <- c("mpg", "vs:carb")
select_columns[["iris"]] <- c("Sepal.Length:Petal.Length", "Species")
```

Names of both lists are the same but some are not included in the `select_columns`!
So at the end I would like to get the same list of tibbles as `dfs` but only with the columns specifed in `select_columns`. If tibble is not mentioned in the `select_columns`, delete it from `dfs`.
I would like to do it using `purrr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(
  dfs[names(select_columns)],
  select_columns,
  ~do.call("select_", c(list(.x), as.list(.y)))
)
```

This goes through pairs data.frame - select vector. In this case, it's:

1. mtcars - c("mpg", "vs:carb")
2. iris   - c("Sepal.Length:Petal.Length", "Species").

On each step it constructs and evaluates a `dplyr::select_` call. For the first pair e.g. the constructed call looks like `select_(mtcars, "mpg", "vs:carb")`. Then results of all the calls are returned in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of `lapply` and `map` would work here. The code:

```
require(dplyr)
require(purrr)

newDfs=setNames(lapply(names(dfs),function(name){
  if(length(select_columns[[name]])>0){
  bind_cols(map(select_columns[[name]],~dplyr::select_(.data=dfs[[name]],.x)))
  }else{
      NULL
    }
}),names(dfs))


newDfs=newDfs[-which(sapply(newDfs, is.null))]
```

Let me know if it works out.

Comment: Didn't see the last part of the question to delete the dfs which are not in ```select_columns```; will edit the answer soon.